# MySQL query calculate user retention in a certain date-range

Tags: mysql, join, retention

I'm trying to select the count of users retaining in a certain date range and that was successful using this query and the table below:

```
+----------+-------------+
| Field    | Type        |
+----------+-------------+
| id       | varchar(17) |
| log_date | date        |
+----------+-------------+

SELECT last_day.log_date, COUNT(distinct last_day.id) as users_num
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT log_date, id
      FROM `userActivity`) this_day
JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT log_date, id
      FROM `userActivity`) last_day
ON this_day.id = last_day.id
AND this_day.log_date = "2018-10-01"
AND last_day.log_date BETWEEN "2018-10-01" AND "2018-10-30"
GROUP BY log_date;
```

But the problem that I'm facing is that I want the assume that every day of the date-range  is day 0. (similar to the following example):

[image: Note that the first row is the avg of the below results I need to calculate]

Note that the first row in the pic is the avg of the below results I need to calculate. Anyone has any idea how can I enhance my query to get the result like the picture?

Comment: What version of MySQL? 5.x or 8.x? I can see a pretty simple solution in 8.x.

Comment: Its version 14.14 distrib 5.7.24 but anyway what was your approach?

Comment: Posted it as a solution, even though you can't really use it in MySQL 5.x

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This solution will only work on MySQL 8.x only since it requires CTEs (Common Table Expressions):

```
with digits as (
  select 0 as n union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4
  union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9
),
series as (
select d1.n * 100 + d2.n * 10 + d3.n as n -- number series from 0 to 999
from digits d1
cross join digits d2
cross join digits d3
)
SELECT last_day.log_date, COUNT(distinct last_day.id) as users_num,
       date_add("2018-10-01", interval s.n day) as current_start
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT log_date, id
      FROM `userActivity`) this_day
JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT log_date, id
      FROM `userActivity`) last_day
ON this_day.id = last_day.id
cross join series s
WHERE s.n <= 30
  AND this_day.log_date = date_add("2018-10-01", interval s.n day)
  AND last_day.log_date BETWEEN date_add("2018-10-01", interval s.n day) 
                            AND date_add("2018-10-30", interval s.n day)
GROUP BY log_date, date_add("2018-10-01", interval s.n day);
```

Comment: Man that was impressing!!! you saved my day!! thank you so much, I'm still studying the query to understand how it works
THANK YOU VERY MUCH! @The Impaler